# specific search in solr

Tags: java, apache, solr

I am using apache Solr for searching my database..!!

Suppose i have indexed 4 columns from one of my table..!!..I just want that only those columns that contains my query term are returned in response..!!..is that possible..??

For example :

I have a table cars with columns : name, displayName, description, extra ..!!

Now i make a query , something like :

localhost:8983/solr/select?q=maruti&wt=json
Now some in some rows only name may contain the word "maruti"

So, In return, i want only name (along with some other fixed fields like ID) ..

Similarly, If description contains this word, then only description should be returned..and not other columns..!!

How can i acheive this..??